# Fetch data from Mysql with specific conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, r, dplyr

I have a Mysql Query which give me below mentioned output:

Output:

```
ID      Date                     T1    T2
A-12    2017-01-01 15:05:20     -3     3
A-12    2017-01-01 15:05:20     -2     5
A-14    2017-01-01 15:05:20      6    -2
A-14    2017-01-01 15:05:20      8     12
A-15    2017-01-01 15:05:20      10    9
A-15    2017-01-01 15:05:20      13    15
A-17    2017-01-01 15:05:20      19    18
```

I want only those rows(distinct with `ID`) having minimum value with comparing `T1` and `T2` value against each `ID` with three additional column one is `Range` and `Minimum` and `Count`.

Range: `-5to5`,`5to10`,`10to15` and `15to20`

Required Output:

```
ID      Date                     T1    T2   Range    Minimum  Count
A-12    2017-01-01 15:05:20     -3     3    -5to5    -3       2
A-14    2017-01-01 15:05:20      4    -2    -5to5    -2       2
A-15    2017-01-01 15:05:20      9     10    5to10    9       2
A-17    2017-01-01 15:05:20      18    19    15to20   18      1
```

My query is:

```
SELECT t1.ID,t1.Date,t2.T1,t2.T2
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.re=t2.re
WHERE DATE(t1.Date)>='2017-01-01';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, once you have connected to your database (e.g. with [`DBI`](https://github.com/r-dbi/RMySQL#readme)), you can do the following with the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
breaks <- c(-Inf, -5, 5, 10, 15, 20, Inf)
labels <- c('-Infto-5','-5to5','5to10','10to15', '15to20', '20toInf')
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Minimum = min(T1,T2)) %>%
  mutate(Range = cut(Minimum, breaks = breaks, labels = labels)) %>%
  mutate(Count = n()) %>%
  filter(T1 == Minimum | T2 == Minimum)
```

Comment: Everything works fine except this line: `(Range = cut(T1, breaks = breaks, labels = labels))` range should be based on `Minimum`.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm.  this is a bit complicated in MySQL

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Date, t2.T1, t2.T2,
       CONCAT(t2.T1, 'to', t2.t2) as range,
       t2.T1 as minimum
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 t2
     ON t1.re = t2.re
WHERE t1.Date >= '2017-01-01' AND
      (T1.ID, t2.T1) IN (SELECT tt1.ID, MIN(tt2.Ti)
                         FROM Table1 tt1 JOIN
                              Table2 tt2
                              ON tt1.re = tt2.re
                         WHERE t1.Date >= '2017-01-01'
                         GROUP BY tt1.ID
                        );
```

Comment: Not worked I want minimum of both `T1` and `T2` against each distinct `ID`.

Comment: After removing the `CONCAT(t2.T1, 'to', t2.t2) as range,` line its working fine, can you just add the `Count` column in your answer rest of the thing i'll try to do in excel or R.

Comment: You have considered only `T2` as minimum without comparing it with `T1`.

Comment: @Roy1245 . . . That is easily fixed in SQL, but you already accepted another answer.

Comment: I have tried to tweak you sql query but couldn't get the required output, if you have the sql query which give me exact required output you can share it with me that will be really helpful.